# OpenIDConnect to Connect to Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3, openid-connect, azure-active-directory

I am using OWIN OpenID Connect Middleware to connect to Azure AD. I am able to authenticate the user successfully and redirect back to callback endpoint. I am a bit confused here as i am receiving only `id_token` & `code` in the response.

```
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Azure AD - TEST",
                Caption = "azure AD",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                ClientId = "some guid",
                Authority = "https://sts.windows.net/idp",
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.CodeIdToken,
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44392/ExternalLogins/Callback/",
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            });
```

Callback Method :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("ExternalLogins/Callback")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
{
    var content = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // I could see the content is a string with id_token, code , state etc.

    //id_token is a JWT, so i can decode it and see the user claims and use them later
}
```

My Questions are  :

1. Is Azure AD used for only authenticating the user ? What about authorizatoin ?
2. If i want to make calls to other APIs after authentication, how do i do that as i don't have `access_token` ?
3. I think i can exchange `code` with `access_token` but not sure which Azure endpoint i need to call to get `access_token` ?
4. What is the difference between  `AuthenticationMode.Active` and `AuthenticationMode.Passive` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Azure AD can absolutely authorize a user and get your Access/Refresh tokens. It supports all oAuth 2.0 and OIDC flows.
2. You'll need to get an `access token` to make calls to an api. Let's say you want to call a /get endpoint on the MS Graph, you will stuff the `access token` into the body of the http request with the keyword `Bearer ey...` in front of it.
   Additionally, you'll need to go into the Azure Portal and configure the delegated permissions you want to access.
3. The auth code is used to exchange for the access_token.  I suggest checking out [this protocol doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) that shows you how to use all the endpoints.  The short answer is you POST to the /token endpoint.
4. The difference between active and passive is a bit complex for a SO answer, I recommend reading [this blog post](https://long2know.com/2015/06/owin-authentication-modes/) about the differences.

I'll just add that if you want to see some sample code using Azure AD you can go to [Azure AD Dev Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-developers-guide)  or [Azure AD code samples on Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=active-directory&type=&language=).